# Is there a way to combine functions so that you combine their derivatives?

Tags: functions, derivatives, special-functions, characteristic-functions

Suppose $y,z$ are functions.

What manipulation: "$?$" to the functions would yield the following? (if any)

$$y?z=y\cdot z\\~\\
\frac {d(y?z)}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dz}{dx}\\~\\
\frac {d^2(y?z)}{dx^2}=\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}\cdot \frac {d^2z}{dx^2}$$

I already know the chain rule is futile here because after the first derivative you have the product in the second.

Comment: All the equations are quite unreadable.

Comment: In your first equality you are saying that $? = \cdot$.

Answer (score 3):

Utterly impossible:
$$y?1=y\cdot 1 = y,$$
$$y' = \frac{d(y?1)}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{d1}{dx} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking. Why are you defining so many letters?

In any case, Convolutions have a property you may be interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration, but you may need some technical conditions on the function space for these to work. In particular, as the linked page mentions, you'll need Fubini's theorem or one of it's generalizations to hold.

Comment: I only used the letters as to depict that the functions could be anything and the nth derivative of the modification would always equal the product of the n-th derivatives of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

With the so-called logarithmic derivative, you can write

$$(\log(yz))'=\frac{(yz)'}{yz}=\frac{y'}{y}+\frac{z'}{z}.$$

This does not generalize to the second order.

Comment: And $\log(yz)\ne yz$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: except when $yz=-W(-1)$.